# Haskell Plugin for XCode 4 under OS X Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, haskell, osx-lion

Is there an alternative to http://www.hoovy.org/HaskellXcodePlugin/ i can use for XCode 4 whilst using Mac OS X Lion ?

Or if it works, how can i build the Plugin under Lion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a solution to Haskell coding in XCode.  Notice the project you referenced was in beta stage 5 years ago, and has not seen any development since!  Your best IDE bet is probably [EclipseFP](http://eclipsefp.github.com/), which has very nice Haskell support in Eclipse.  This is what I use.  The only disadvantage is using the clunky Eclipse interface instead of the elegant XCode interface.